# Log IP of users who click a button?

Tags: database, ip

Is it possible to create a new database table to log the IP addresses of users who click a specific button? This is a bit above my PHP/JS skill level so I'm trying to gauge the difficulty of doing this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the button works.

For instance, you can make an API. When the button is clicked, you can call the api via Ajax and save the IP during the process.

Or most likely you will write ip via action hook, if the button call the hook. In this case, you will use user agent.

Comment: the button as it is now is just a term acceptance button that closes a modal and sets a cookie. so guessing the second option is the easier solution?

Comment: @user8792133 if the button call the Wordpress hook, yes.

Comment: Thank you @idpokute - I set it up using this method: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305735/is-there-any-reason-only-1-my-ip-would-be-added-to-this-table-using-wpdn-ins if you have a chance to quickly check it out and see if this is on the right track.