# Is there any reason only 1 (my) IP would be added to this table using $wpdn->insert?

Tags: plugin-development, database, cookies, ip

I'm using a small custom plugin to create a table in the database and then add a user's IP address to the table if a certain cookie exists (this cookie is set elsewhere by clicking a term acceptance button). When testing I was able to get my IP to show up in the table, but I tried testing on my mobile device and using Browserstack and still the only IP that shows up in the table is my own. Is there any reason why this might be happening? The plugin code is as follows:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'table_name_here';

 if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
     //table not in database. Create new table
     $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

     $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            ip VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (ip)
     ) $charset_collate;";
     require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
else {
}

/*
 * Add IP to Table
 */

if ( isset( $_COOKIE['cookie_name_here']  ) ) { 
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'ip' => $ip
        )
   );
}
```

Comment: Is this to make sure there is only a single login session? There are easier ways to do that, and this fails with NAT anyway. E.g. a conference of 1000 people on wifi might all share the same IP

Comment: @TomJNowell The purpose is just to log the IP of everyone who accepts the terms actually. Some weird GDPR related thing the lawyers want done.

Comment: I would hire new lawyers, users IPs can be considered personally identifiable information, introducing liability

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell but the reasoning is what Bjorn mentioned below - the IP isn't stored unless the terms are accepted and cookie is created. Just trying to see if this should work as is

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same internet connection on multiple devices? Perhaps your mobile is connected to the same wifi network. Visit http://icanhazip.com in your mobile to see its IP. As for browserstack perhaps they aren't accepting the cookie so their IP doesn't get recorded. You should record the timestamp as well so you can correlate it with visits during testing.

Also you should be doing the table creation during plugin activation and not checking for that needlessly with every script execution. [Here's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) the hook you can use for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will add that hook in! When testing on mobile I turned off Wi-Fi to avoid that issue but the mobile IP doesn't appear to be stored in the DB.